# Evaluation of integral consisting rational function of exponential and power of x:

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

Consider the following integral :

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{(a+bx)^n}{e^{cx}-1}dx$$

Here a,b,c,n are constants

How to calculate above integral ?

Also, similarly:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+ix)^{2n-1}-(1-ix)^{2n-1}}{e^{2πx}-1}dx$$

How to calculate this for n=1,2..?

I know the following:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+ix)^{2n}-(1-ix)^{2n}}{e^{2πx}-1}dx=\frac{i
(2n-1)}{2(2n+1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You should first try and figure out when the integral converges in the first place(looking at the limit in $x = 0$) and then maybe try per partes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the integral converges, you could write
$$\frac{(a+bx)^n}{e^{cx}-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-c (k+1) x} \,(a+b x)^n$$ and, at the price of a simple change of variable, it could look that the sum of incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

## A partial result for the final integral.

> Notation: $C$ is the binomial coefficient,
> $$C(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x-y+1)\Gamma(y+1)}$$

You can use a binomial expansion and notice that the even terms cancel to obtain
$$(1+ix)^{2n}-(1-ix)^{2n}=2\sum_{k=0}^{2n} C(2n,2k+1)(ix)^{2k+1}$$
And using an obvious property of the odd powers of the imaginary unit this is
$$2i\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^{k}C(2n,2k+1)x^{2k+1}$$
So
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+ix)^{2n}-(1-ix)^{2n}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\mathrm{d}x=2i\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^{k}C(2n,2k+1)\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\mathrm{d}x$$
But the final integral is very well known, in particular
$$\mathcal{M}\left(x\mapsto \frac{1}{e^x-1}\right)(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$$
Which I believe can be evaluated using Ramunajan's Master Theorem. Anyway this means that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+ix)^{2n}-(1-ix)^{2n}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\mathrm{d}x=2i\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^{k}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2k-1)!(2k+1)!}\frac{\Gamma(2k+2)\zeta(2k+2)}{(2\pi)^{2k+2}}$$
$$=2i(2n)!\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k}\zeta(2k+2)}{(2n-2k-1)!(2\pi)^{2k+2}}$$
But of course, the [value of the zeta function at even integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers) is well known. We have
$$\zeta(2(k+1))=(-1)^k\frac{(2\pi)^{2k+2}B_{2k+2}}{2(2k+2)!}$$
Therefore
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+ix)^{2n}-(1-ix)^{2n}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\mathrm{d}x=i(2n)!\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{(2n-2k-1)!(2k+2)!}$$
$$=i\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}C(2n,2k+1)$$
We can show that
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}C(2n,2k+1)=\frac{(2n-1)}{2(2n+1)}$$
Because, due to the poles of the Gamma function at the negative integers, letting $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$,
$$C(n,k)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n-k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}=\begin{cases}
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} & k\leq n\\
0 & k>n
\end{cases}$$
Hence
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}C(2n,2k+1)$$
Now we go by induction. The result is clearly true for $n=1$ since
$$a_1=\frac{B_2}{2}C(2,1)=B_2=\frac{1}{6}=\frac{2\cdot 1-1}{2(2\cdot 1+1)}$$
Inductive step:
$$a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}C(2n+2,2k+1)$$
$$a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}C(2n,2k+1)+2\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}C(2n,2k)+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}C(2n,2k-1)$$
Where we have dropped the last term of the first sum due to the properties of the binomial coefficient mentioned before.
Noting our defn. of $a_n$ and rearranging,
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}\bigg(2C(2n,2k)+C(2n,2k-1)\bigg)\right]$$
Again using the recursive properties of the binomial,
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac{B_{2k+2}}{2k+2}\bigg(C(2n,2k)+C(2n+1,2k)\bigg)\right]$$
And I must admit, I'm not sure where to go from here! Hopefully someone else can finish off the rest?

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir but unfortunately I'm looking for the 2nd integral ( i.e. with odd powers)

Comment: @GSA_1 Yes, in hindsight I focused on the wrong thing. I am unfortunately rather busy at the moment so I don't have time to write up a full answer. Though I think following the same path (i.e, expanding using binomial theorem) will likely yield good results.